# Jest: Run ESLint after tests using --watch

Tags: jestjs, eslint

Is there a way to run ESLint everytime Jest's watch script triggers? I want to automatically have the watch script lint (with `--fix`) my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jest-runner-eslint plugin to do exactly what you described.

https://github.com/jest-community/jest-runner-eslint